# SQL Trigger Conditional Insert - number of supplied values error

Tags: sql, triggers

I've cobbled together a trigger based on some answers I found here that I think is close, but is returning a supplied value error that I'm not sure how to fix. In short I have a ParticipationStatus table that I want to add a record to that will include the UserID of the inserted and a status of 'Pending' whenever a user RoleID of '19' is inserted in the UserRole table.

The Participation_Status table has a few other fields, but the only one that is required is an auto_id column. Here is what I have so far that is throwing a "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition." Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_insert_status_participation] ON [dbo].[UserRoles]
FOR INSERT AS

BEGIN

If (SELECT RoleID FROM INSERTED)=19

DECLARE @UserID int
DECLARE @Status nvarchar(50)

INSERT INTO ParticipationStatus
VALUES (@UserID, @Status)

SET @UserID = (select UserID from inserted) 
SET @Status = 'Pending'
END
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be assigning values to variables before insertion? And also, how many fields do you actually have in the table?

Comment: You may be right. I can't find the link, but I had been following the approved answer for what appeared to be a similar question. In terms of the number of fields there are ten, but I didn't see how that mattered and had set-up other triggers in which that wasn't an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INSERTED` can have more than one row. You need to code your trigger accordingly. It's actually much simpler this way.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_insert_status_participation] ON [dbo].[UserRoles]
FOR INSERT AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO ParticipationStatus(UserID, Status)
SELECT UserID, 'Pending' FROM INSERTED
WHERE RoleID = 19


END
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed much more simple. Works great.